# Why IotHub events are delayed when stored in Time Series Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-timeseries-insights

I have a Time Series Insights Environment with an IoT Hub data source configured.

What I noticed is that there is a specific 20-30 seconds delay from sending an event to IoT Hub and seeing it stored in TSI.

After I found this, I attached a Function Trigger directly to the Iot Hub. What happened is that events were received immediately by the trigger, but TSI returned them 20-30 seconds later.

So, I have two questions:

1. Where does that delay come from?
2. Is there anything I can do about minimizing the delay?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an expected measurable delay of up to 1 minute before you will see it in TSI and you cannot dial that up/down.  It's just how the service works.

Just in case you haven't already, also make sure you've configured your SKU and capacity to support your use cases.

Comment: thanks for your input. "expected" sounds like "by design" which leads me to think that there could be improvements in this. SKU is not an issue in our case as we are currently in a PoC stage with one device sending events once per minute. Your explanation surprises me, having in mind the advertised scale of this service.